# SQL WHERE clause perfromance issue AX2012R3

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am trying to optimize a query.
Note that I am using Microsoft Dynamics AX and traced this query to SQL.
The query except for the index hints is being generated by Dynamics and I am wondering if I have to rewrite the whole statement in AX or if I can fix this by simply adding changes to indexes.
The query is as follows:

```
SELECT        T1.PARTITION, T1.DECIMALPRECISION, T1.RECID, T1.RECVERSION, T1.SYMBOL, T1.SYSTEMOFUNITS, T1.UNITOFMEASURECLASS
    FROM            UNITOFMEASURE AS T1 WITH(INDEX(I_4436SYMBOLIDX))
    WHERE        T1.PARTITION = 5637144576 AND EXISTS
                                 (SELECT        'x' AS Expr1
                                   FROM            UNITOFMEASURECONVERSION AS T2 WITH(INDEX(I_4438CONVERSIONIDX))  

                                   WHERE        (T2.PARTITION = 5637144576 ) 
                                   AND (T2.PRODUCT = 5637297578 OR T2.PRODUCT = 0) 
                                   AND (T1.RECID = T2.FROMUNITOFMEASURE) 
                                   AND (T2.TOUNITOFMEASURE = 0) OR
                                                             (T2.PARTITION = 5637144576) AND (T2.PRODUCT = 5637297578 OR
                                                             T2.PRODUCT = 0) AND (T1.RECID = T2.TOUNITOFMEASURE) AND (T2.FROMUNITOFMEASURE = 0))
```

This query returns the following execution plan:
You can see it reads 5 342544 records. The corresponding tables contain 1342 and 3984 records.
[image]

If i remove the first `T1.PARTITION = 5637144576`where clause, the query executes how it should.
This is the updated query:

```
SELECT        T1.PARTITION, T1.DECIMALPRECISION, T1.RECID, T1.RECVERSION, T1.SYMBOL, T1.SYSTEMOFUNITS, T1.UNITOFMEASURECLASS
FROM            UNITOFMEASURE AS T1 WITH(INDEX(I_4436SYMBOLIDX))
WHERE        EXISTS
                             (SELECT        'x' AS Expr1
                               FROM            UNITOFMEASURECONVERSION AS T2 WITH(INDEX(I_4438CONVERSIONIDX))  

                               WHERE        (T2.PARTITION = 5637144576 ) 
                               AND (T2.PRODUCT = 5637297578 OR T2.PRODUCT = 0) 
                               AND (T1.RECID = T2.FROMUNITOFMEASURE) 
                               AND (T2.TOUNITOFMEASURE = 0) OR
                                                         (T2.PARTITION = 5637144576) AND (T2.PRODUCT = 5637297578 OR
                                                         T2.PRODUCT = 0) AND (T1.RECID = T2.TOUNITOFMEASURE) AND (T2.FROMUNITOFMEASURE = 0))
```

Now it uses the following execution plan:
[image]

Here's more information about the indexes used:
[image: I_4436SYMBOLIDX]

[image]

Can I optimize the performance by changing the indexes ?
Or do I have to rewrite the functionality by building the query myself in Dynamics AX 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is a mess.  The `OR` in the `EXISTS` is going to kill performance.  So, use multiple `EXISTS` clauses.  I think this is the logic:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM UNITOFMEASURE AS T1 
WHERE T1.PARTITION = 5637144576 AND
      (EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM UNITOFMEASURECONVERSION T2
               WHERE T2.FROMUNITOFMEASURE = T1.RECID AND
                     T2.PARTITION = 5637144576 AND
                     T2.PRODUCT IN (5637297578, 0)  AND
                     T2.TOUNITOFMEASURE = 0 
              ) OR 
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM UNITOFMEASURECONVERSION T2
               WHERE T2.TOUNITOFMEASURE = T1.RECID AND
                     T2.PARTITION = 5637144576 AND
                     T2.PRODUCT IN (5637297578, 0) AND
                     T2.FROMUNITOFMEASURE = 0
              )
      );
```

Then you want indexes on:

- `UNITOFMEASURE(PARTITION, RECID)`
- `UNITOFMEASURECONVERSION(RECID, PARTITION, PRODUCT, FROMUNITOFMEASURE, TOUNITOFMEASURE)`

I think the second index is useful for both subqueries.

Actually, if I interpreted the query correctly, it can be written as:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM UNITOFMEASURE AS T1 
WHERE T1.PARTITION = 5637144576 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM UNITOFMEASURECONVERSION T2
              WHERE T2.FROMUNITOFMEASURE = T1.RECID AND
                    T2.PARTITION = 5637144576 AND
                    T2.PRODUCT IN (5637297578, 0)  AND
                    (T2.TOUNITOFMEASURE = 0 OR T2.FROMUNITOFMEASURE = 0)
             );
```

And the above indexes should work.

Comment: The query automatically generated by MS Dynamics AX 2012 R3 CU13 is indeed a mess.
From your answer I can conclude that I will need a code change in the application. The issue at hand is occurring in a production environment, hence why i was looking for an alternative solution through indexation on the databases in SQL Server.
I will look for an alternative solution in the application and release it through an ALM procedure.
Thanks for taking your time to answer my question, i will mark your post as the answer.